# How to access json nested array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access json array but still failed. I have following array

```
{
    "response": {
        "error": [
            "name is already exists",
            "email@gmail.com is already exists"
        ]
    }
}
```

I know this is very common question and already there are hundreds of answers and tutorials but i am still failed. So can someone kindly guide me. I would like to appreciate.

I have tried following script but it showing `undefined`

```
response.error
response.error[0]
response['error'][0]
```

Comment: What is the name of your object ?

Comment: it looks like you need `yourObject.response.error`

Comment: What do you means? `response` if from ajax success `success: function(response){...}`

Comment: can you provide a full code of your ajax function with console.log responses

Comment: @MuizAhmed You are showing us an object. This object is stored inside a variable. We need to get this variable name. Try with `response.response.error[0]`

Comment: @qiAlex thank you so much you have already answered +1

Answer (score 2):

Try code the example below.

```js
var json = {
    "response": {
        "error": [
            "name is already exists",
            "email@gmail.com is already exists"
        ]
    }
};

alert(json.response.error[0]);
alert(json.response.error[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not pointing to JavaScript the object. 
You need to create a variable, and associate to your object.

Example: 
`variableName.response.error`

For more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON